# ChromeDriver - stale element reference

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, element, autoit, stale

I'm using ChromeDriver on Windows with AutoIt.

Work flow is like this: navigate to page, find element (input field), post text, submit is OK = so far, so good.

I a few seconds (also tried 30-40 seconds), repeat all operations, using exact same data (URL, text....)

Element is detected correctly both times, but submitting text second time fails with "stale element reference" error.

Find element AutoIt instruction:

`$sElement = _WD_FindElement($sSession, $_WD_LOCATOR_ByXPath, "//*[@placeholder='Add comment']")`

Result find element - first run:

`__WD_Post: StatusCode=200; ResponseText={"value":{"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"76f56981-6062-40e5-a0d0-d1f9176141f7"}}... _WD_FindElement: {"value":{"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"76f56981-6062-40e5-a0d0-d1f9176141f7"}}`

Send text and submit - first run:

`URL=HTTP://127.0.0.1:9515/session/9fb1b3b3195ceaa07a4cfe3666a3f10e/element/76f56981-6062-40e5-a0d0-d1f9176141f7/value; $sData={"id":"76f56981-6062-40e5-a0d0-d1f9176141f7", "text":" XXXXX XXXXX"} __WD_Post: StatusCode=200; ResponseText={"value":null}...`

Notice the same value is used, all OK: 76f56981-6062-40e5-a0d0-d1f9176141f7

Result find element - second run:
`__WD_Post: URL=HTTP://127.0.0.1:9515/session/9fb1b3b3195ceaa07a4cfe3666a3f10e/element; $sData={"using":"xpath","value":"//*[@placeholder='Add comment']"} __WD_Post: StatusCode=200; ResponseText={"value":{"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"e99cbe99-9b67-475d-b1aa-98028cb5d26e"}}... _WD_FindElement: {"value":{"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"e99cbe99-9b67-475d-b1aa-98028cb5d26e"}}`

New element is found: e99cbe99-9b67-475d-b1aa-98028cb5d26e

Send text and submit - second run:
`URL=HTTP://127.0.0.1:9515/session/9fb1b3b3195ceaa07a4cfe3666a3f10e/element/e99cbe99-9b67-475d-b1aa-98028cb5d26e/value; $sData={"id":"e99cbe99-9b67-475d-b1aa-98028cb5d26e", "text":" XXXX XXXX"} __WD_Post: StatusCode=404; ResponseText={"value":{"error":"stale element reference","message":"stale element reference: element is not attac... __WD_Post ==> No match: {"value":{"error":"stale element reference","message":"stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document\n  (Session info: chrome=109.0.5414.75)","stacktrace":"Backtrace:\n\t(No symbol) [0x00596643]\n\t(No symbol) [0x0052BE21]\n\t(No symbol) [0x0042DA9D]\n\t(No symbol) [0x004309E4]\n\t(No symbol) [0x004308AD]\n\t(No symbol) [0x00430B30]\n\t(No symbol) [0x0045C474]\n\t(No symbol) [0x0045B7AB]\n\t(No symbol) [0x0047FD7C]\n\t(No symbol) [0x0045641F]\n\t(No symbol) [0x004800D4]\n\t(No symbol) [0x00496B09]\n\t(No symbol) [0x0047FB76]\n\t(No symbol) [0x004549C1]\n\t(No symbol) [0x00455E5D]\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x0080A142+2497106]\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x008385D3+2686691]\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x0083BB9C+2700460]\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x00643B10+635936]\n\t(No symbol) [0x00534A1F]\n\t(No symbol) [0x0053A418]\n\t(No symbol) [0x0053A505]\n\t(No symbol) [0x0054508B]\n\tBaseThreadInitThunk [0x772200F9+25]\n\tRtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77BA7BBE+286]\n\tRtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77BA7B8E+238]\n"}} _WD_ElementAction: {"value":{"error":"stale element reference","message":"stale element reference: element is not attac... _WD_ElementAction ==> No match: {"value":{"error":"stale element reference","message":"stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document\n  (Session info: chrome=109.0.5414.75)","stacktrace":"Backtrace:\n\t(No symbol) [0x00596643]\n\t(No symbol) [0x0052BE21]\n\t(No symbol) [0x0042DA9D]\n\t(No symbol) [0x004309E4]\n\t(No symbol) [0x004308AD]\n\t(No symbol) [0x00430B30]\n\t(No symbol) [0x0045C474]\n\t(No symbol) [0x0045B7AB]\n\t(No symbol) [0x0047FD7C]\n\t(No symbol) [0x0045641F]\n\t(No symbol) [0x004800D4]\n\t(No symbol) [0x00496B09]\n\t(No symbol) [0x0047FB76]\n\t(No symbol) [0x004549C1]\n\t(No symbol) [0x00455E5D]\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x0080A142+2497106]\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x008385D3+2686691]\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x0083BB9C+2700460]\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x00643B10+635936]\n\t(No symbol) [0x00534A1F]\n\t(No symbol) [0x0053A418]\n\t(No symbol) [0x0053A505]\n\t(No symbol) [0x0054508B]\n\tBaseThreadInitThunk [0x772200F9+25]\n\tRtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77BA7BBE+286]\n\tRtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77BA7B8E+238]\n"}}`

Even tough new element is found and used, I get error!

If I close the program completely and run it again, only first run works OK, same problem afterwards.

I have tried to use different variables.

I have tried to not reload page (Navigate 1 time, submit 1 = OK, submit 2 = fail).

I have tried to add pause / wait 30-40 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: delete session, create new session, navigate to new address.